# How to upload my app to the App Store in different iPhone/ipad sizes

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, swift, ipod

I've made a new app without using "Auto Layout" for iPhone 5 size only.
I can make the same app for the other iPhones&iPads sizes,
But how or where can I upload it to the App Store in different sizes?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to submit same app just with different sizes for different phones? You can use the same codebase and add support for different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You should re consider doing this.

But if you are hell bent in doing so, you can make new targets in your xCode, each one for each device size for iPhone/iPad. Add images to respective targets.

Then to submit each one differently as a different app, you will need to make new and different provisioning profile for each one.

To support different devices here's a great tutorial on supporting [Adaptive Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial). All you have to do is to add constraints that would work.

Comment: Got it, thanks! But how can I upload all the app versions to the Appstore? Btw, why not doing this? Can you tell me a better solution?

Comment: I would be able to much better answer the question if you tell me why do you want to do this in first place? Do you want to sell different apps for different prices (people have done this in past)
I don't recommend doing this, because many times Apple rejects similar apps, or re-skinned apps.

Comment: Uploading different versions would be straightforward. You will make new IPA for each one and create a new instance on itunesConnect for each and upload your new IPAs to each respective new instance.

Comment: If all you want to do is to support all different dimensions, you need to take a look at Adaptive layout in xCode. It will help you support all different dimensions using single codebase, upload as a single app and run perfectly on all devices.

Comment: I want to upload only 1 app to the App Store that will support all the devices. But, I've created my app for iPhone 5 only, without using "auto layouts", and I can't use "auto layouts" because it ruins all the labels that I've created that change their position in the view whenever something happens. I would really like to know how to do it without ruining the layouts positions.

Comment: @EliBunimovich Updated my answer for adapting to different device layouts. Give that tutorial a go, let me know if you run into any troubles. :)

Comment: Its a ridiculous thing to attempt, how will users find and know which version to download? You'll have to name each app differently and in order for users to find the correct size your app name will have to reflect that. If Apple see what you're doing they'll probably reject it. Not to mention what if you submit one size app and when Apple do a review they test it on a different size device it'll immediately get rejected anyway.

Comment: @MrH yeah, my point exactly. And Apple won't probably reject it, they'll DEFINITELY reject it. As of late they've been rejecting reskins.

Comment: @iosDev82, my comments directed at the op by the way, not at your answer.

Comment: @MrH and I was agreeing with you anyway. :D

Comment: @IosDev82. We're all in agreement. ;-)

Comment: @iosDev82 Look, I am using your guide, and it works perfectly, but when i use my code for changing my label position (for example:
'self.minutes.frame = CGRectMake(271.0, 80.0, 112.0, 160.0)' ) the label start to move to places I don't tell him to go